# Passing object between pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have encountered a little problem and need some help

What I would like to do is pass an object from one page and pass it to another page.

This is no problem with C# as the code would look like.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public class Class1
{
    private String firstName;
    private String surName;
    private int age;

    public Class1()
    {

    }

    public String FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value; }
    }

    public String SurName
    {
        get { return surName; }
        set { surName = value; }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set { age = value; }
    }
}
```

And The forms look like

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        class1.FirstName = textBoxFirstname.Text;
        class1.SurName = textBoxSurname.Text;
        class1.Age =  int.Parse(textBoxAge.Text);

        Form2 form2 = new Form2(class1);
        form2.Show();
    }
```

And

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Class1 class1;

    public Form2(Class1 class1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.class1 = class1;

        label2.Text = (class1.FirstName + " " + class1.SurName);
        label4.Text = Convert.ToString(class1.Age);
    }
}
```

This is what I have come up with so far

And These are the pages

```
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        class1.FirstName = TextBoxFirstName.Text;
        class1.SurName = TextBoxSurname.Text;
        class1.Age = int.Parse(TextBoxAge.Text);

        //Missing code
    }
    }
```

And this is the 2nd form

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Details"></asp:Label><br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>

    <br />

    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <br />

</div>
</form>
</body>
```

and here is the back code

```
public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //missing code to display label 3

        //Missing code to display label 5
    }
}
```

Comment: `form2.Show` in ASP.NET? Use one of [these ways](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6c3yckfw(v=vs.100).aspx) to pass values between ASP.NET Web Pages.

Comment: Do you need to pass the *actual object* to the other page?  That sounds like a dependency on server-side statefulness that you may want to avoid if possible.  Can you just pass an *identifier* for the object and re-fetch it from data on the second page?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate(v=vs.110).aspx):

Save your informations you need (e.g. a instance of your Class1) in a session and reuse it in another page:

On Page1 in `Button_Click`:

```
Session["YourSessionName"] = class1Instance;
```

On Page2 in `Page_Load`:

```
if (Session["YourSessionName"] != null) //Check if session is empty
{
    Class1 class1InstanceOnPage2 = (Class1)Session["YourSessionName"];
}
```

And then you can reuse all your stuff from the class.
This also works with strings etc.

But this only applies to ASP.NET and not to WinForms.

I don't understand why you mix it up, its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.Net, you do not pass objects directly into other pages. In a sense, the pages are disconnected from each but joined only by user input.

To pass data, rather than objects (which is the correct way to think of it), you can pass it via the querystring, if it is not private and you are not worried about tampering, via the Session object, if it needs to be private or via a database where it is stored and then retrieved in another page.

Web is different than a native app!